# Why do I get different results when linear regression when using scipy.stats.linregress vs numpy.polyfit(deg=1)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-regression

I have a scatter plot which I want to fit a linear line of best fit to. The raw data is below:

```
x = [2,5,10,20,30,50]
y = [0.0013,0.0018,0.0067,0.0081,0.009,0.013]
```

When I use

```
numpy.polyfit(x,y,deg=1)
```

and

```
scipy.stats.linregress(x,y)
```

I get different values for the slope and intercept. Why is this? I thought that maybe they are using slightly different algorithms, but the scipy version gives me a line that overestimates all of my data.

Is the scipy function only for a specific application? Is there a way to reconcile this difference?

I would like to know when to use which and the applicability of each function.

Thank you.

EDIT: Results in the form slope, intercept

```
scipy: 0.000257290802691 0.00826916605228

numpy: 0.0002322   0.00212209
```

EDIT: Mistake was in a line of code that was changing my result for scipy. These functions do in fact give the same results to the level of accuracy I need.

Comment: How different are they? Can you post the slope/intercept given by each?

Comment: Running your two lines, I'm getting nearly identical slope/intercept, the only difference is from rounding. You know that you shouldn't ever check for exact equality on floating point numbers, right?

Comment: @scnerd added results

Comment: The slopes are nearly identical but the y intercept in scipy makes it so that my line overestimates all of my data.

Comment: I can't reproduce your numbers. For numpy I get `array([ 0.00025729,  0.00826917])` and for scipy I get: `LinregressResult(slope=0.00025729080269099627, intercept=0.0082691660522839668, ...)`

Comment: @scnerd your statement is such an annoying misconception. It depends entirely on what you're doing, you just need to understand what you're doing.

Comment: @will I know it's not impossible to do direct equality comparison on floats, but you should only do it if the exact same computations are being performed on your inputs. In this case, since he's running different numpy and scipy functions and comparing their results, what you want to know is if the results are _effectively_ the same, not necessarily bitwise identical. For such a case, using `==` is a common mistake that might be the cause of his confusion, telling the OP that the values are "different" when in fact they're extremely close.

Comment: @scnerd the slopes you could call extremely close, but the intercepts are different by a factor of 4, not very close in my opinion, causing such a difference that it throws off my whole results.

Comment: @scnerd fair enough. But in that case, so you're aware, python already sort of does this, sort of - it has some [quirks](https://repl.it/repls/ShockingLeadingInitialization).

Comment: @MWaz please see my answer below. I agree, being off by such a large factor isn't "close", but based on your MCVE I'm not getting any such discrepancy, so there's no way for us to help you debug your code. Please try updating your packages if possible to see if there's a bug in an older version of these modules, or run the four lines exactly like I do below to see if the exact same code produces different outputs.

Comment: @MWaz the intercepts being off by a *factor of four* is irrelevant - the intercepts are so small compared to your inputs that they're probably meant to be zero...

Comment: @will possibly, but a bigger question becomes why these two functions behave differently. The values given by his MCVE are nowhere near where floats might start becoming unstable, so we'd expect numpy and scipy to behave very similarly. The OP asks why the functions don't behave similarly, which would be a fair question if we could reproduce an example where they don't. Also, his input `y` values are on that same order of magnitude, there isn't really any difference in scale going on here.

Comment: @will Look at the inputs again... they are of the same order of magnitude.

Comment: MWaz, Which version of numpy and scipy are you using?  (Check `numpy.__version__` and `scipy.__version__`.)  I get the same results as in @scnerd's answer.  Your numpy result does not look right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's the issue with the code, here's what I get when I run your exact snippet:

```
In [1]: x = [2,5,10,20,30,50,100,200,300]
   ...: y = [0.0013,0.0018,0.0067,0.0081,0.009,0.013,0.077,0.085,0.057]
   ...: print(numpy.polyfit(x,y,deg=1))
   ...: print(scipy.stats.linregress(x,y))
   ...:
[0.00025729 0.00826917]
LinregressResult(slope=0.0002572908026909962, intercept=0.00826916605228397, rvalue=0.7851975581052358, pvalue=0.012170749250986976, stderr=7.669358704600765e-05)
```

As you can see, I get:

```
       slope              intercept
numpy  0.00025729         0.00826917
scipy  0.0002572908026... 0.0082691660...
```

Which is identical besides rounding. Here are my library versions:

```
In [14]: numpy.__version__
Out[14]: '1.14.2'

In [15]: scipy.__version__
Out[15]: '1.0.1'
```

See if updating your libraries has any effect, otherwise update your example code to make sure you get the same issue as your actual code.

Comment: I changed the input, trimming the last three values.